# elasticsearch.yml : will the configuration file be written on the fly?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am building my own docker image for the elasticsearch application.

One question I have : **will the configuration file `elasticsearch.yml` be modified by the application on the fly?**

I hope that will never happen even if the node is running in cluster. But some other application (like redis), they modify the config file on the fly when cluster status changes. And if the configuration file changes on the fly, I have to export it as volumn since docker image can not retain the changes done on the fly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't run any risk of overwriting your configuration file. The configuration will be read from that file and kept in memory. ES also allows to persistently change settings at runtime, but they are stored in another global cluster state file (in `data/CLUSTER_NAME/nodes/N/_state`, where `N` is the 0-based node index) and re-read on each restart.

Comment: so I only need export the data dir as volume.  thank you